# inject a custom function-name with a fixed signature into CRTP

Tags: c++, templates, c++17, crtp

I want to inject a **name** for a to-be-create function with a quite fixed signature into CRTP (Curiously recurring template pattern) base class.

Here is my working existing code ([coliru MCVE link](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dab230d25baed22c)) :-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
//--- library layer ---
template<class O,class Under> struct Crtp{
    Under* oNo=nullptr;
    auto getUnderlying(){
        return oNo;   
    }
};
//--- user layer ex 1 ---
struct B{  // please don't edit this class
    int k=0;
};
struct BO : Crtp<BO,B>{
    auto getBOUn(){ return Crtp<BO,B>::getUnderlying();}
    // some other functions
};
//--- user layer ex 2 ---
struct C{ // please don't edit this class
    int kad=0;
};
struct CO : Crtp<CO,C>{
    auto getCOUn(){ return Crtp<CO,C>::getUnderlying();}
    // some other functions
};

int main() {
    BO bo; B b; bo.Crtp<BO,B>::oNo=&b;  //<-- please don't edit
    std::cout<< bo.getBOUn()->k; 
}
```

I wish it would be easy like :-

```
//--- user layer ex 1 ---
struct B{  // (same)
    int k=0;
};
struct BO : Crtp<BO,B,getBOUn>{  //<--- so easy and clean
    // some other functions
};
```

Is it possible, how?

I have >100 class pairs like `B` & `BO` ; they have their own unique custom names for `getBOUn()`-like function.

I can fix it with macro, but I don't want another layer of mess.
Please don't answer using macro.

### **Real use cases**

I often create classes like this :-

```
struct Walkable{
    float stamina =0 ;
    float speed =0;
};
struct WalkableO: Crtp<WalkableO,Walkable>{
    auto getWalkUnderlying(){ return Crtp<BO,B>::getUnderlying();}
    void runNow(){
        if(getWalkUnderlying()->stamina >1 ){
             getWalkUnderlying()->speed +=3;
             getWalkUnderlying()->stamina --;
        }
    }
};

class Dog : public virtual WalkableO, public virtual HasHpO, public virtual EatenableO {};
```

Sometimes, I like to access a specific underlying directly :-

```
Dog* dogPtr; /** some ini ...*/ dogPtr->getWalkUnderlying()->stamina=10;
```

Sometimes, I want to access the *"some other functions"* in a more abstract way :-

```
dogOPtr->runNow();  //a custom function within WalkableO
```

I use virtual inheritance because if I re-design to make e.g. every `WalkableO` to **be** `HasHpO` too, I can just edit the code like below.
I don't even need to change `Dog` code:-

```
struct WalkableO: Crtp<WalkableO,Walkable>, virtual HasHpO{/*something*/};
```

`Dog` itself, can be a base class on `BullDog`, `TigerDog`, etc.

Comment: Why do you need a function in `BO` that calls `getUnderlying`? Why not use `getUnderlying` directly and save yourself a whole lot of trouble? Otherwise, the CRTP base is kind of pointless.

Comment: What is the purpose of the "underlying" pointer? Are you implementing the pimpl idiom? If so, I'm sure you could come up with better names than `Crtp` and `getUnderlying`.

Comment: @Kerndog73  Thank for the good question.  I answer it in my post because it is an information that I should tell.  I am implementing a public-implemention (similar but not the same as pimpl).

Comment: Why are you using virtual inheritance? It's rarely a good idea to use virtual inheritance. Are `WalkableO`, `HasHpO` and `EatenableO` interface classes? I still don't understand what you mean by "underlying". Can you show `WalkableO` and `Dog` in more detail please?

Comment: @Kerndog73 I add more detail.  Please let me know if your want more.

Comment: Your design seems rather complicated. Perhaps more complicated than it needs to be. Why does `WalkableO` store a pointer to `Walkable`? Why not avoid CRTP altogether and just do `struct Walkable { float stamina = 0; float speed = 0; void runNow(); };`? You seem to be overusing inheritance. You've got a `Dog` class that inherits **multiple** classes using **virtual** inheritance and then you've got some more classes that inherit `Dog`. Your design might be a lot cleaner if `Dog` didn't inherit `WalkableO` but instead, held and instance of it. Is there a reason you're not doing that?

Comment: Your design is massively simplified if you eliminate superfluous inheritance. Given the definition of `Walkable` from my previous comment, `Dog` becomes `struct Dog { Walkable walkable; HasHp hasHp; Eatenable eatenable; };`. This is significantly easier to understand and reason about.

Comment: @Kerndog73 I can't do that because I am using pool.  I store every `Hp` in a contiguous array. Every `Walkable` in another contiguous array, etc.  This way, I can iterate `Hp` very fast, but iterate `Dog` a little slower.  It is affordable because I need to iterate every `Hp` much more often than iterate every `Dog`.   This approach leads to an extra pointer usage and the superfluous inheritance.

Comment: Now I understand! Have you heard of the Entity-Component-System architecture? I contribute to one of the best (in my books it's **the** best) C++ ECS framework, that is, [EnTT](https://github.com/skypjack/entt). I strongly recommend you check out EnTT! You could join [the Gitter chatroom](https://gitter.im/skypjack/entt) to discuss EnTT with the experts.

Comment: @Kerndog73   Ha, yes, I am developing an ECS library and using it for my game. Thank for your link.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, your choices for declaring a new function are quite limited.

In this case, you are introducing a new [*identifier*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/lex.name#nt:identifier).  After [preprocessing](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/cpp), an *identifier* can only be introduced by a [*declaration*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.dcl#nt:declaration).  Under your constraints, the only three relevant kinds of *declaration*s are [*simple-declaration*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.dcl#nt:simple-declaration)s, [*function-definition*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.fct.def.general#nt:function-definition)s, and [*template-declaration*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp#nt:template-declaration)s (on top of a *declaration*, which has to be a *simple-declaration* or *function-definition* in this case since it should declare a function).  In a *template-declaration*, the only name(s) you declare is(are) the name(s) declared in the underlying *simple-declaration* or *function-definition*, so we are basically limited to *simple-declaration*s and *function-definition*s.  The names introduced by a *simple-declaration* or a *function-definition* are specified in its [*declarator*](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.decl#nt:declarator)s, so there is no way to specify a new *identifier* and automatically declare it either.

In other words, there is no way to pass to-be-declared identifiers around “transparently” after preprocessing in C++.  So I don't think what you are trying to do is possible.  You have to either use a macro, or declare the functions yourself.

Comment: Unfortunately, this answer might be the one I need to hear.  Thanks.

Comment: @cppBeginner You could try EnTT. As Kerndog73 mentioned, it's a pretty good library

Comment: @Sneaky Turtle ::  I had previewed that great library before.   AFAIK, this issue can't be solved by EnTT.  I just love Object-Oriented so much and wish for an elegant way to mix OO with ECS.   Partially lucky, macro can mix it elegantly.

Comment: @cppBeginner OO and ECS don't mix. They're almost opposites. IMHO, ECS done right is much more elegant than OO. If I'm being brutally honest, the code in the question is not elegant. Maybe you could ask a question about the problems you had with EnTT?

Comment: @Sneaky Turtle  Haha, yes, it may be just my own belief.   I somehow ask it in another SO question  - they answer "Don't do it!".